# Server Configuration for nodejs App and nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have an app running 
App is running perfectly.I can access to the root url. But cant access other urls. App is built with nodejs express framework. My server OS is Ubuntu 17. 
I need to run my app in http://35.202.2.217 not in some other port.
Thats why i am using proxy pass. I am stuck here. What do i have to do

for example, http://localhost:1336/pages

i am using nginx.

my nginx codes

```
upstream adshackers {
        server 10.128.0.2:8082;
        server 10.128.0.2:9082;
        server 10.128.0.2:3082;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
        root /var/www/html;
        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name adshackers.com;
        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        proxy_pass http://adshackers/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;


                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        # 
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Comment: Try removing the tailing slash from `proxy_pass http://adshackers/;` i.e. your `proxy_pass` should be `http://adshackers`

Comment: removed the tailing slash and the php part, and voila...its working..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've cleaned it a bit and remove the php part, unless you're also serving php files.

```
upstream adshackers {
           server localhost:1336;
}

server {
       listen 80 default_server;
       listen [::]:80 default_server;

       root /var/www/html;

       server_name adshackers.com;

       location / {
            proxy_pass http://adshackers;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       }
}
```

The upstream part must contain the info for proxying requests to your app. I have assumed your app is hosted on the same machine as your nginx is running and is listening `localhost:1336` as your example shows.

In that case, when an http request comes to adshackers.com (if DNS entries are correct), nginx will transfer the request to `localhost:1336`.

Comment: removed the tailing slash and the php part, and voila...its working..thanks